# XML Query (Xpath)

Tags: xml, xpath

i am trying to get the all details about spesific actors, and to find this spesific actors i have function that recieve XMLDoc and 2 strings parameters: First name and Last name, and in my code below i always get 0 NodesElements. can someone tell me what i am doing wrong please?

```
 public XmlNodeList Query3(XmlDocument xmlDoc, String actorFirstName, String actorLastName)// returns all the awards of all TV-shows of an actor
        {
string s = "Netflix/movies/movie/actors/actor[first-name="+actorFirstName+"last-name="+actorLastName+"]";
            XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(s);
            foreach (XmlNode x1 in xmlNodeList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x1.InnerText);
            }
            return xmlNodeList;
}
```

XMlDoc:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Netflix>
  <movies>
    <movie>
      <name>Mister Glass</name>
      <genre>Drama</genre>
      <year>2019</year>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>James</first-name>
          <last-name>McAvoy</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1979 </year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Alliance of Women Film Journalists</category>
              <year>2007</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>ALOS Awards</category>
              <year>2018</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Bruce</first-name>
          <last-name>Willis</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1955 </year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>American gun rights advocates</category>
              <year>2007</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>American film producers</category>
              <year>2013</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>American male video game actors</category>
              <year>2012</year>
            </award>
            <award>

.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
[first-name="+actorFirstName+"last-name="+actorLastName+"]";
```

to

```
[first-name="+actorFirstName+" and last-name="+actorLastName+"]";
                              ^^^^^
```